# Azure CDN management over API (Authentication issue)

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

So basically I want to manage a CDN from an API. The only thing I'm stuck with is authentication. HOW DO I DO THAT? I found it for blob storage and various other services, but not for CDN's. Does anyone got an idea or could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Azure CDN` can be managed via REST API, documentation of which can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634456.aspx.

Authentication/Authorization for this happens using `Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)`. You may find this link helpful for that purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx.

Comment: How to manage the CDN was clear, i just got stuck with authorization. That worked now. Thanks